# pesquisar milhares de strings em milhares de arquivos

Tags: regex, powershell

Estou com o seguinte problema: nosso sistema é parametrizável, e esses parâmetros ficam em uma tabela. Só que nos últimos 25 anos muitos programadores mexeram no sistema e criaram e usaram esses parâmetros sem documentá-los. Por isso estou com esta tarefa de documentar isso.

A primeira parte é localizar todos estes parâmetros em toda a base de código do sistema, que é feito em ASP clássico, ASP.NET, C#, Delphi, Oracle pl/sql e JavaScript.

Preciso pesquisar mais de 3500 strings em mais de 20000 fontes, eliminando ao máximo os falso-positivos, que são nomes de campo iguais aos nomes de parâmetros, variáveis internas com nome igual ao dos parâmetros, etc, etc, etc, por isso preciso pesquisar essas mais de 3500 strings garantindo que elas estejam entre plics ('), ou entre aspas (") ou entre espaços, tabs, pontos, ou no começo ou no final da linha.

Estou usando para isso um script em powershell.

A expressão abaixo me atende em quase tudo, menos quando a string aparece no começo ou no final da linha:

```
(?sm)[\s\W]+WS_URL_CONSULTA_CNPJ_SERASA[\s\W\n]+
```

Alguma dica de como eu faria para incluir como condição a string acima aparecer no começo da linha OU no final da linha? Sendo que nestes casos ela não estaria entre plics ou aspas.

Comment: Você poderia usar a tua regex com as seguintes adições: `^(?sm)[\s\W]+WS_URL_CONSULTA_CNPJ_SERASA[\s\W\n]+` para as strings iniciadas pela sua regex ou `(?sm)[\s\W]+WS_URL_CONSULTA_CNPJ_SERASA[\s\W\n]+$` para as string terminadas com a sua regex.

Comment: Olá. Sua sugestão não resolve o problema mas me deu uma dica pra resolver o problema: usar várias expressões. Eu fiz assim:     [\s\W]+WS_URL_CONSULTA_CNPJ_SERASA[\s\W]+|[\s\W]+WS_URL_CONSULTA_CNPJ_SERASA[\s\W]*$|^[\s\W]*WS_URL_CONSULTA_CNPJ_SERASA

Answer (score 0):

Se tiver certeza de que cada parâmetro começa e termina com um carácter de palavra (`[0-9_a-zA-Z]`), pode usar [limites de palavra `\b`](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/borda.html#2_3_3).

```
$regex = [regex] "\b$( $WS_URL_CONSULTA_CNPJ_SERASA )\b"

$data -match $regex
```

```
"Encontrou: $($matches[0])"
```